# How to edit xib in Xcode 10?

Tags: xcode, xcode10, xcode10.1

I followed several tutorials in which there are some options at the right bottom of the screen like this:

[image: tutorial's Xcode option!]

that allows entering images, texts, etc.
but in my Xcode, there are no such options so I can't find anyway to edit my LaunchScreen.
[image: my Xcode, with no button to choose an image or anything else!]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Xcode - 10.x shifted the option above**

Check the below image and click on the arrow pointed button.

[image]

Comment: please don't answer obvious duplicates: instead, vote to close as duplicate.